# Reduce PNG bytes by manipulating color type - not having success with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to see if I can reduce the bytes of a PNG by changing the png color type. I am trying to keep the dimensions as high as possible (100 or 150 ideally). The images are not complex and I thought I could use Indexed-Colour (Colour Type 3) with 1 bit depth, but my approach does not seem to be working. Has anybody had success with this?

[image]

I see in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/png/#11IHDR):
[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879356/how-to-create-png-image-with-color-type-3-and-bit-depth-1) seems to cover the topic, but I ran a few tests:

When I run this:

```
magick identify A.png
```

I got this:

```
A.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1676B 0.000u 0:00.001
```

I ran this:

```
convert A.png -type palette -depth 1 convertedA.png
magick identify convertedA.png
```

And the result was:

```
convertedA.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3c 1544B 0.000u 0:00.002
```

I ran these commands:

```
convert A.png -background white -flatten -type palette -depth 1 -colors 2 c1A.png
magick -identify c1A.png
```

And the result was:

```
c1A.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 1532B 0.000u 0:00.001
```

I ran the updated command in the thread:

```
A.png -background white -flatten -type palette -depth 1 -colors 2 output.png
magick identify output.png
```

and got:

```
output.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 1532B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

So they are still 8-bit and the size hasn't changed significantly (1,676 to 1,544 to 1,532 to 1,532).

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203823/reducing-colors-in-a-png-image-is-making-the-file-size-bigger) as well, but it's somewhat dated.

Comment: 672 of your 1600 bytes are an ICC profile. And you have 168 colours. Maybe try `magick YOURIMAGE -colors 2 -strip result.png` and see if that's closer to what you want.

Comment: Wow `strip.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 264B 0.000u 0:00.001` that's a lot smaller.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, how did you see all of that in the png? Is there a program you use to inspect them?

Answer (score 0):

Your image contains 168 colours and 672 bytes of ICC profile. You can see both those statistics using **ImageMagick** as follows:

```
magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE
```

Or you can just count the colours with:

```
magick -format %k GbeWF.png info:
168
```

You can probably also see the size of the ICC profile with:

```
exiftool -v YOURIMAGE
```

---

I don't know what you are really trying to do, but you can remove the ICC profile and reduce the colours to 2 using:

```
magick YOURIMAGE -colors 2 -strip result.png
```

Then inspect it again with:

```
magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE
```

and look near the end of the output for the size in bytes, the PNG color mode and PNG bit depth.

Comment: Any luck with this answer?